# Multiline input box values are added to sum

Tags: javascript

I want to implement multiple rows, add values from two input boxes, and let third input get this sum value. But now I only implement one line. How can I set it up to achieve multiple rows? Do you need to add an ergodic function?
Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type="text" id="num1" value="20">  
<input type="text" id="num2">  
<input type="text"  value="" id="sum">  <br>

<input type="text" id="num1" value="30">  
<input type="text" id="num2">  
<input type="text"  value="" id="sum">  <br>

<script>  
window.onload = function(){  
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){  
        inputs[i].onblur = function(){  
            var add1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;  
            var add2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;  
            document.getElementById("sum").value = add1*1 + add2*1;  
        }  
    }  
        }  
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmRA8.png)

Comment: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element. the value must be unique within the HTML document.

Comment: hi,If you can, can you write an example for me? I want to study, first learn JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is exact working code:

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
rows.forEach(row => {
  let input = row.querySelector("input.add");
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => {

    let val1, val2;
    if (parseInt(row.querySelector(".first").value)) {
      val1 = parseInt(row.querySelector(".first").value);
    } else {
      val1 = 0;
      // alert("Please enter some number in first field");
    }

    if (parseInt(row.querySelector(".add").value)) {
      val2 = parseInt(row.querySelector(".add").value);
    } else {
      val2 = 0;
      // alert("Please enter some number in second field");
    }

    row.querySelector(".result").value = val1 + val2;
  });
});

function sum() {
  document.getElementById("totalSum").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("result1").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("result2").value);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="first" value="20">
  <input class="add">
  <input id="result1" class="result">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input class="first" value="20">
  <input class="add">
  <input id="result2" class="result">
</div>
<div class="">
  <button type="button" name="button" onClick="sum();">SUM</button>
  <input id="totalSum"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: It's cool. But when I double-click the middle input box, I did not enter the content. When I moved the mouse and clicked another box, the input box on the far right appeared wrong. You can have a try? it reminds "NaN" error!

Comment: @adjsn222 fixed the issue. You can add validations as well. For example if any of value is empty show alert and ask to fill value first.

Comment: it usefull very much! I haven't used stackoverfollow. before
I look at how to go to accept the answer?

Comment: I ordered the hook, and it's now green. It should be through. :-D

Comment: Technical God! :)

Comment: cool! But I found a problem. When I did not fill in, clicking the last sum button, it had NaN error.

Comment: if i want this id=“totalSum” button to change in real time without this submission button? Can this function be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same id twice.

Pack the 3 input fields in a div.

loop though divs and the Children should be

[0] num1

[1] num2

[3] sum

If you have further questions just ask

Comment: HI! If you can, can you write an example for me? I want to study, first learn JS

Comment: the code snippet from @VicJordan should do the job. No point writing it again.

Answer (score 0):

its a string add but easy to fix have no time for more ;)

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
rows.forEach(row => {
  let input = row.querySelector("input.add");
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    row.querySelector(".result").value = parseInt(row.querySelector(".first").value) + parseInt(row.querySelector(".add").value);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="first" value="20">
  <input class="add">
  <input class="result">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input class="first" value="20">
  <input class="add">
  <input class="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,Very feeling. It is when I add, for example: I add 5., it becomes 205. instead of 25? How to solve it?

Comment: @adjsn222 check my answer, I have fixed it.

Comment: Hi, VicJordan: Now it is ok! thank you very very much! Best regards! Robin

Comment: Hi, VicJordan:I also want to ask how to add multiple “result” values to a single input to get the final sum.

Comment: @adjsn222 read the line above next time so you know why it adds as a string and not as number

Comment: @VicJordan I'll read your code carefully. It's very helpful. Can you update the code and get the sum of all class= "result" separately? I want to study and study it well.